# Which directories are private to specific users by default on UNIX-based systems?

Tags: linux, unix, filesystems

Which directories and files in UNIX-based file systems have default user permissions set? For example, a user's home directory can't be seen by other users on a system without his permission. What other directories have their permissions set in this way when a user account is created? `/etc`? `/bin`? Others?

Comment: This is not a programming question.  Voted to move to superuser.com.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Also are you aware of the difference between user/group/other permissions?

Comment: Yes, the directories that user has permission to access when he is logged in . For eg.in /bin directory user can't add new files he can just read them .So can you give me list of all such top-level directories that have such permission.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the distro but generally regular users only have write access to files under their home directory along with a couple folders for temporary files.  What they have read access varies even more. If you wanted to change the default permissions of new users' home directories, you'd probably modify `/etc/skel` on most systems.

Comment: you can make files inside of /tmp

Comment: Yes, I was lumping that in with "a couple folders for temporary files", as the exact path can vary.

Answer (score 0):

Many system files have read and or execute permissions for other users(users which are not the user owning the file-usually root for system files, and are not in the same group as the user who owns the file (such as the root group).

Answer (score 0):

Try man hier to find out the directory structure for your distribution.